# Accuracy of Auto Encoder (Image Reconstruction) model in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to make a simple autoencoder model for Image reconstruction along with MSNIT dataset.
Now if I run this model, it presents me with accuracy.

'60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 83us/sample - loss: 0.0373 - accuracy: 0.2034 - val_loss: 0.0368 - val_accuracy: 0.217
'.

but I am not sure how its calculated given that the prediction results itself are an image.
I dug deep till function "sparse_categorical_accuracy" but was not able to reach any conclusion about the formula for accuracy.

```
latent_dim = 64 

class Autoencoder(Model):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim   
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'),
    ])
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid'),
      layers.Reshape((28, 28))
    ])

  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded

autoencoder = Autoencoder(latent_dim)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=10,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

Comment: There is no accuracy here, only mean squared error.

Comment: Added the right matrix